# How to change head location to another folder?

Tags: git, github, git-shell

My master branch is currently syncing with a local folder `W:\folder2`.

I'd like my master branch to sync with local folder `W:\folder1` instead.

How can I do this?

I was playing around, while learning, in GitShell with `git worktree add <second path>` and `git checkout master` and `git checkout -b <new branch>` commands.

Before, my master branch was synced with local folder `W:\folder1`.
Now it's synced with local folder `W:\folder2`.

I think I accidentally switched something.

How do I switch it back?

Comment: Branches in git are not folders !!! you are confusing branches with folders

Comment: Thank you ... I'll remember this moving forward ... do you hear my concern?

Comment: @CodeWizard, [worktrees let you check additional branches at separate paths](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree)

Comment: I agree @steveax but he has confusing branches with folders.

Answer (score 2):

## ***`git worktree`***

Git worktree was introduced in 2007 under the `contrib` folder in git repo and was called `new-workdir`.

In **git V2.5** it was named `worktree` and it allow you to have multiple instances of the same repository across different folders.

for example:

```
git worktree add <second path>
```

will create another folder on your computer which allow you to work on different branch simultaneously.

---

If you want to remove the worktree use the prune subcommand

> ***`prune`***
>   Prune working tree information in $GIT_DIR/worktrees.

Another option to remove it is to delete the `.git/worktrees` folder

Comment: How do I remove all worktrees except one local folder W:\folder1?

Comment: Use the prune flag

Comment: I'd simply like my master branch to be syncing with one local folder

Comment: What's the syntax for a prune subcommand? "git --prune <path>"?

Comment: So delete the other one. see the last line of the answer

Comment: Where is this folder? I don't see it locally

Comment: Under the original repo you started with

Comment: I don't see this folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107253/discussion-between-faalbane-and-codewizard).